# Gnome-terminal doesn't start any more after auto login to X

Tags: linux

Tell me please is there any way to resolve this issue without installing a login manager please?

I've enabled the auto login for startx, following the steps from the beyond link:

[How to make auto login work in Ubuntu? (no display manager)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679419/how-to-make-auto-login-work-in-ubuntu-no-display-manager)
Auto login is functioning now.

On the device is a command line installation from Minimal Lubuntu 16.10 mini.iso. without any desktop, only the Kernel and some restricted modules. The only environment installed is fluxbox.

After booting in Fluxbox, I can't open gnome-terminal at all, until I will not do the next steps. xterm can start.

ctrl+alt+del in the running Fluxbox, it will redirect me for a second-two in tty, but because auto login is enable it will redirect me back automatically from tty1 to Fluxbox. So, in order to remain in tty I will keep pressing continuously ctrl+c.

Now, being in tty I will

```
sudo -i
su myusername
startx
```

Being again in fluxbox, I can run the terminal normally.

Do you please have any clues please, why I can't open the terminal without doing the above?

Trying to start gnome-terminal from xterm when at the first login.

```
    gnome-terminal
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

Excuse me, I am not sure that `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is active or not.

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23357560/)

Output of `env` from xterm (after logging manually again to startx)

```
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
WINDOWID=8388621
XTERM_SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
SUDO_USER=xdpsx
SUDO_UID=1000
USERNAME=root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PWD=/home/xdpsx
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
XTERM_LOCALE=en_US.UTF-8
XTERM_VERSION=XTerm(324)
HOME=/root
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/su
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=root
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
DISPLAY=:0.0
SUDO_GID=1000
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XAUTHORITY=/home/xdpsx/.Xauthority
COLORTERM=truecolor
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Output of `ps aux | grep dbus` from xterm (after logging manually again to startx)

```
    message+   668  0.0  0.0   6420  3936 ?        Ss   19:11   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
nobody     811  0.0  0.1   9316  4000 ?        S    19:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
xdpsx     1375  0.0  0.0   6136  3460 ?        Ss   19:11   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
xdpsx     1381  0.0  0.0   6136  3316 ?        S    19:11   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
xdpsx     1505  0.0  0.0   7004   312 ?        S    19:12   0:00 dbus-launch --autolaunch fedd8908d0d244c498876a97f5b34c28 --binary-syntax --close-stderr
xdpsx     1506  0.0  0.0   6136  3060 ?        Ss   19:12   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
xdpsx     1529  0.0  0.0   6136  3356 ?        S    19:14   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
root      1834  0.0  0.0   5144   828 pts/1    S+   19:25   0:00 grep --color=auto dbus
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I am seeing a similar problem since upgrading to Ubuntu 16.10. I discovered that I can fix the environment and start gnome-terminal like this:

```
dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd --all
gnome-terminal &
```

If that doesn't work, then you could try this:

```
dbus-launch gnome-terminal &
```

Comment: I've had a similar issue, now when I run gnome-terminal nothing ever happens, but when I run dbus-launch gnome-terminal it always works. same with nautilus now only dbus-launch makes it actually start. no idea why this is happening